# Blurry Render Issue with Detailed PNG Background in Blender's Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, output

I'm working on a project in Blender's Video Sequence Editor where I have a transparent video of a spinning logo overlaid on top of a webpage mockup (PNG). The PNG is quite large and contains a lot of detail.

[image]

My problem arises when I render the video. Despite setting the export options for maximum quality, the background PNG becomes extremely blurry, losing much of its detail.

I have attached a screenshot of my Blender setup and the settings pane.
Does anyone have any tips on how to maintain the sharpness of the PNG upon render? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Graphics in video is always a pain. Try some loosles codec (I don't have an experience with blender's codecs probably PNG?) ... Personally I would try render PNG image sequence and import into image editor (like Photoshop as layers) and export as animated GIF. Or share your blend with packed images to let us see.